# How do I read node from neo4j using py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm a python + neo4j noob. Trying to access my data on graphenedb using py2neo in my python flask web app.

I have spent hours trying to do something simple. All I want to do is get a node from the db based on its property.

Been trying the following but it is returning an empty array to client:

```
    niagara = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService(<my graphenedb url>)

    people = niagara.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "People")
    results = people.get("alias","BigDog")

    return json.dumps(results)
```

The only time I have been able to return the node in its entirety is when I access it by its id:

```
    return json.dumps(niagara.get_properties(niagara.node(0)))
```

Any help would be spectacular.

Answer (score 5):

try NodeSelector

```
from py2neo import NodeSelector,Graph,Node
graph = Graph('http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data')
selector = NodeSelector(graph)
user_node = selector.select("Label",property_key=value).first()
```

this retrieves the first node ; nodeselector return iterator u can cast it to list as well

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are just creating the index but never adding your node to it? Also, you could do that transparently in neo4j 2.0 with Cypher, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-schema-index.html

via the Cypher REST endpoint which I believe is exposed via the Python bindings too, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html

Answer (score 0):

Returning an empty array in this case is correct behaviour. You have created an index and then - as Peter says - not added anything to it before executing the `get` method. Each index entry point may contain zero or more nodes and as nothing has been added, this returns an empty collection.

Use the [get_or_create](http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/indexes/#py2neo.neo4j.Index.get_or_create) method instead to create a node if none already exists - this should also only return a single node.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting my head around indexes. I really just want to read a node from the database that I have created previously via the neo4j console.